# Difference between OnClosing and Form_Closing or OnLoad and Form_Load

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form in a VSTO addin.  It has two methods, OnClosing and Form_Closing.

What is the difference between these two?

I can't seem to figure it out with any of the docs.

Same goes for OnLoad and Form_Load.

Thanks

EDIT: Comment said that OnClosing is now OnFormClosing.  Well if that is the case what is there an OnFormLoad?  And does it really matter what it's called, considering I have to register the events anyway?

For example I have OnResize as well, are any of these methods being called?  I mean I never registered them anywhere. Like I did the Form_Load and Form_XXX functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this all comes about because you cannot call an event in any class other than the one that defined it.

So, for example, take this class `Foo` & a derived type `FooChild`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Bar;
}

public class FooChild : Foo
{
    public void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bar = this.Bar;
        if (bar != null)
        {
            bar(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

When this is compiled I get the error:

> The event 'Foo.Bar' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Foo')

So, how do I raise the event from a child class?

We add a `OnBar` method to `Foo`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Bar;

    protected virtual void OnBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bar = this.Bar;
        if (bar != null)
        {
            bar(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in `FooChild` it appears like I can access the event in two ways:

```
public class FooChild : Foo
{
    /* FIRST WAY */
    public FooChild()
    {
        this.Bar += BarHandler;
    }

    private void BarHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Do Stuff */
    }

    /* SECOND WAY */
    protected override void OnBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBar(sender, e);
        /* Do Stuff */
    }
}
```

The first way is the way any code can attach to the event on `Foo`. Its semantics are that "the event has been fired and I'm responding to it".

The second way is slightly different. If it is implemented as above it is effectively the same as the normal handling method. But it can do something more powerful. Its semantics are "some code in the `Foo` class hierarchy has requested that the event **should** be fire, but I'll make the final decision if it **will** be." Here's some code that could do that:

```
public class FooChild : Foo
{
    protected bool _suppressBarEvent = true;

    protected override void OnBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressBarEvent)
        {
            base.OnBar(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

So, in this example we have overridden whether the `Bar` event will be fired or not. This affects all of the event handlers that have attached.

That is the true purpose of the `On###` methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [recommended pattern for implementing events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2(v=vs.90).aspx).

Each Event `Foo` has a corresponding protected method `OnFoo`. The method is responsible for triggering the event. (By default the designer will create event handlers named `ctrl_Foo`).

This means that *most* of the time Event registration should be used, but there are some times when it may be required to override the `OnFoo` implementation. Do this *only* when it's required.

The fact that the project does *both* probably indicates a coding mispractice.

Comment: My point is if I never register them, it doesn't matter what I name the function?

Comment: OnClosing is an protected (bordering on private) method. There is one of these. However, you can register as many Event Handlers you want (ie. different methods) to the same Event.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods which doing different jobs

`OnLoad` is method which triggers an event

`Form_Load` is "event handler", method which executes when event was triggered.